# In MySQL, what is the difference between "WHERE my_bool_col = 1" and "WHERE my_bool_col"

Tags: mysql

I came across a query today, which uses where conditions on two columns. Here is an example of the query:

```
select * from users where age = 21 and consent_given = 1;
```

I have an index on age and an index on consent_given. When I run `explain` on this query, it uses an index_merge of both these indexes.

**Note for duplicating issue:** this index merge only happens if there are enough users meeting those conditions; the table i'm using has about 2.5 million rows and 3,500 of them meet the conditions.

I've discovered that this query runs much faster if it only uses the `age_index` and doesn't merge to also use the `consent_given_index`.

I've already figured out several ways to optimize this query (create composite index, hint to use the age index, delete the consent_given index, anything else?), but what really has me stumped - why does the query below not use the consent_given index, and only uses the age index, therefore optimizing the query?

```
select * from users where age = 21 and consent_given;
```

Shouldn't `consent_given` be doing the exact same thing as `consent_given = 1`? When I run `explain` on this, the consent_given_index isn't even listed under possible_keys - mysql doesn't consider it an available index. Can anyone explain the difference in MySQL between specifying `=1` and not specifying, in relation to indexes?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Output for first query explain:

```
id            => 1
select_type   => SIMPLE
table         => users
type          => index_merge
possible_keys => users_age_index, users_consent_given_index
key           => users_age_index, users_consent_given_index
key_len       => 767,1
ref           => NULL
rows          => 1,886
extra         => Using intersect(users_age_index,users_consent_given_index); Using where
```

Output for second query explain:

```
id            => 1
select_type   => SIMPLE
table         => users
type          => ref
possible_keys => users_age_index
key           => users_age_index
key_len       => 767
ref           => const
rows          => 3,774
extra         => Using index condition; Using where
```

Comment: share the query plan

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin have just added the explain outputs - is that enough info?

Comment: what is your left column in times of index creation ? does it (age,consent_given) or (consent_given,age)

Comment: It's age,completed

Comment: users_age_index that means this is you composite key name am i right?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't have a composite index there yet. I'm just wondering why it treats "consent" differently to "consent = 1". I thought they would be treated the same?

Comment: if you use just column name in where mysql just do true ,false that means boolean checking